# Can terminators swim?

Tags: the-terminator-series

I'm mainly interested in the swimming capabilities of the T-800, T-1000, and 
T-X, though it's fine to speak of the other terminators as well.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your dad?

Comment: "Gents, take a walk!" - Captain Barabossa

Comment: That depends on the model.  The T-X almost certainly cannot, the T-1000 almost certainly can, and I doubt Arnold himself could stay afloat, let alone his robot form.